# Why does my QIntValidator allow inputs not in my specified range?

Tags: c++, qt, validation, qlineedit

I am trying to set up a QIntValidator to validate input on a QLineEdit. This is what I did:

```
userInput = new QLineEdit("1");
userInput->setValidator(new QIntValidator ( 1, 20, this ) );
```

This appears to work: it does not allow any letters in. However, I can type in `0`, which is out of range, and I can also type in numbers like `21`, `39` and `80`, all out of range of 1-20. Basically, I expect that the QIntValidator will only allow number inputs in the range 1-20, but, instead, I find that it allows all nonnegative number inputs less than 100 (I can also do `00000`.)

Why is the QIntValidator not working as I expected it to and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you done any research regarding the effect? What have you found?

Comment: If I read the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qintvalidator.html#validate) right, the validator does not prevent inputting invalid, but *potentially* valid values (that's the `intermediate` state). I assume such 'intermediate' input is discarded on the line edit losing focus, but try yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` is accepted as `QValidator::Intermediate` state, because the user may intend to type e.g. `05`, which would be valid. You won't be able to actually *input* the undesired value. After you press <kbd>Return</kbd> or move focus from the widget, having `0` in the input field, the value should return to the original (well, at least spinboxes behave so, not sure about `QLineEdit`).